# OOPHP Mysql form vote system

Tags: php, mysql

I have a application where the user can choose from 2 images. If the user chooses image 1, it gets +10 score and a +1 up vote. Image 2 gets at the same time -10 score and a +1 on the down vote.

I have made a script but it not function properly.

Keep in mind that there are 2 input submit buttons one for both images.

$itemArray[key][0] = item 1 random out of the database
$itemArray[key][1] = item 2 random out of the database

Database = id / naam / description / score / upvotes / downvotes

Can you help to make this code efficiently? 
Is it smarter to use AJAX?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['item1'])) {

    //if item1 is chosen it gets +10 in score and +1 in upvote
    $item1Id = $itemArray['id'][0]; //id from the item
    $item1Score = $itemArray['score'][0] + 10; //the current score + 10
    $item1Upvotes = $itemArray ['up_votes'][0] + 1; //the current upvotes +1
    $item1Downvotes = $itemArray ['down_votes'][0] + 0; //downvotes + 0

    $item->setId($item1Id); //sets id
    $item->setScore($item1Score); //sets score
    $item->setUpvotes($item1Upvotes); //sets upvotes
    $item->setDownvotes($item1Downvotes); //sets downvotes

    //saves it in the database
    $item->updateScore($item->getId(), $item->getScore(), $item->getUpvotes(), $item->getDownvotes());

    //item 2 gets -10 in score and +1 in downvotes
    $item2Id = $itemArray['id'][1];
    $item2Score = $itemArray['score'][1] - 10;
    $item2Upvotes = $itemArray ['up_votes'][1] + 0;
    $item2Downvotes = $itemArray ['down_votes'][1] + 1;

    $item2->setId($item2Id);
    $item2->setScore($item2Score);
    $item2->setUpvotes($item2Upvotes);
    $item2->setDownvotes($item2Downvotes);

    $item2->updateScore($item2->getId(), $item2->getScore(), $item2->getUpvotes(), $item2->getDownvotes());
}

if (isset($_POST['item2'])) {

    $item2Id = $itemArray['id'][1];
    $item2Score = $itemArray['score'][1] + 10;
    $item2Upvotes = $itemArray ['up_votes'][1] + 1;
    $item2Downvotes = $itemArray ['down_votes'][1] + 0;

    $item2->setId($item2Id);
    $item2->setScore($item2Score);
    $item2->setUpvotes($item2Upvotes);
    $item2->setDownvotes($item2Downvotes);

    $item2->updateScore($item2->getId(), $item2->getScore(), $item2->getUpvotes(), $item2->getDownvotes());

    $item1Id = $itemArray['id'][0];
    $item1Score = $itemArray['score'][0] - 10;
    $item1Upvotes = $itemArray ['up_votes'][0] + 0;
    $item1Downvotes = $itemArray ['down_votes'][0] + 1;

    $item->setId($item1Id);
    $item->setScore($item1Score);
    $item->setUpvotes($item1Upvotes);
    $item->setDownvotes($item1Downvotes);

    $item->updateScore($item->getId(), $item->getScore(), $item->getUpvotes(), $item->getDownvotes());
}
```

?>

```
<form action="" method="post">
    //image 1
    <input type="submit" name="item1" value="Vote" />
    //image 2
    <input type="submit" name="item2" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? _(Are you getting a particular error message?)_

Comment: It is sort of working, but sometimes a item gets the wrong score or votes if i check it in the database. Like if you have voted for item1, item2 gets the score +10 and +1 upvote. I hope you guys understand me if not dont be afraid to ask.

Comment: I think you're repeating a lot of code, use the features of OOP such as constructors and class methods. Ajax is useful only if you need a dynamic page, without reloading the page.